# How do I persist and restore my defstruct's to a file?

Tags: clojure

I want to persist my data to a file and restore the data when I rerun the program.

I've defined my defstruct as such:

(defstruct bookmark :url :title :comments)

Program will simply do the following:
1. Load the defstruct's from url-db.txt
2. Read from an import file(s) passed into *command-line-args* and add to internal data var.
3. Rewrite the url-db.txt file.

Sample import file:

www.cnn.com|News|This is CNN
www.msnbc.com|Search|
news.ycombinator.com|News|Tech News

Comment: Someone tripped over this problem before me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923029/clojure-slurping-structs-from-file-fails-with-string-attributes-containing-white

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tom Crayford's answer is close, but use the "pr" function instead of "print".  "pr" produces strings that can be read back in with "read".

```
(defn save-db [db filename]
  (spit 
   filename 
   (with-out-str (pr db))))

(defn load-db [filename] 
  (with-in-str (slurp filename)
    (read)))
```

Note that this will not work if *print-dup* is set to true.  See [ticket #176](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/clojure/tickets/176)  Note also that when you read the database back in, the records will be ordinary maps, not struct maps.  Struct maps cannot yet be serialized with pr/read.

Comment: Just for my own edification, is there a reason you used with-in-str and with-out-str instead of using read-string and pr-str?

Comment: Not really.  Don't remember why I wrote it that way.

Comment: When would reading it as an ordinary map instead of a struct map be a problem?  I haven't encountered a place where they were not interchangeable.  In this case, though (generalize as you need), you could merge each record into an empty bookmark as you do the reading.

Answer (score 3):

Use spit and slurp (example taken from http://www.nofluffjuststuff.com/blog/stuart_halloway/2008/09/pcl__clojure_chapter_3_1). Generally this technique is called serializing.

```
(defn save-db [db filename]
  (spit 
   filename 
   (with-out-str (pr db))))

(defn load-db [filename] 
  (with-in-str (slurp filename)
    (read)))
```

(The earlier print error was there in the original code, and I was dumb and didn't check it. Thanks)

Comment: (def x (struct bookmark "news.ycombinator.com" "News" "Tech News")); Doesn't handle "Things in quotes"

Comment: His example had a name in quotes.  When I tried to reload the data it didn't work (save-db x "url-db.txt") ... (def y (load-db "url-db.txt"))